# Problems with jquery ui slider-range when switching jquery 1.4.4 to 1.5.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I tried to upgrade from jquery 1.4.4 to 1.5.2 but encounter errors regarding the slider-range from jquery UI 1.8.11.

Anyone found a solution to this problem?

```
        $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 75, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with how i cached changes:
Working solution caches changes like this:

```
$( "#slider-range" ).bind( "slidestop", function(event, ui) {
        search();
});
```